# Can sublime 3.0 convert display from plain text to source color scheme automatically?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm little new to Sublime, wanted to know if there is a way to change display in sublime-3.0 from plain text to source colors automatically (i.e. Sublime should keep source colring from where code was copied and pasted like- HTML or XML or Java code) without I changing it manually.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: No but `emacs` can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text already does this for some languages, like XML.

It works when you have a blank document that is set to Plain Text format (i.e. you open a new tab), and paste something in whose first line can be identified to be a specific language, using regular expressions.

For XML, it looks for an [XML prolog](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) or an XML element with a namespace. [Regex](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/0efdfc4698139ff3c4d7e0b901ac87dbea3cbfe4/XML/XML.sublime-syntax#L13-L18)

For HTML, it looks for [a HTML doctype](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/c469cddbfb89bb6a8213cb6a5004fd34db94a85e/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax#L12).

It currently doesn't support Java - I guess it's not easy to come up with a regex that would match only the first line of a Java file and not a C# file, for example. If you do have some ideas, you can use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer to edit the relevant `.sublime-syntax` (YAML) file and add a `first_line_match` in.

You may also find the following packages helpful:

- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoSetSyntax
- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax

Extra note: these "first line matches" also apply when opening files that aren't automatically matched to a syntax by the file's name/extension.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but I've done it with the Package control `ctrl+shift+p (Win, Linux) or cmd+shift+p (OS X)`. Search for `Package Control: install Package`, press Enter and then search whatever package you need.

After installing the `SCSS` package, I'd get the HTML colouring as well.